# Inconsistent font-size between normal text and inline-code

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here's [an actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27998899/2564301) that was posted just now, as viewed by Safari.

---

[image]

---

The font sizes are all over the map, tiny code, huge code, medium text. Why aren't the fonts all the same size?

Comment: Confirmed for Safari on the iPad (although it appears in Ugly Courier, not in Nice Consolas(?)). The inline code tick font size is off.

Comment: Confirmed in FF on Windows, too. The issue is that space-indented block code is small, while inline backtick code is large.

Comment: Aren't those backtick code blocks missing highlight formatting? (I'm not 100% sure if they used to be formatted)

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that code blocks are wrapped inside a `pre` element, which have `font-size: 13px`. Inline code (and normal text) inherit `font-size: 15px` from `.post-text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. It will be on live after our next production build. Code font size should be 13px both inline or in block form.